# ¿Cómo ejecuto un script en segundo plano en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando consultar un API cada 5 segundos, para tener la información actualizada y funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
while True:
    prueba()

def prueba():
    print("PRUEBA CON EL TIEMPO")
    time.sleep(60)
```

Funciona, pero el problema es que no continua haciendo nada más porque continua con ese proceso y quiero que solo lo haga en segundo plano.

Comment: Si estas trabajando en Linux deberias de probar con el demonio Cron para que ejecute tu script cada determinado tiempo. https://www.linuxtotal.com.mx/?cont=info_admon_006

Comment: No sé si te entendí correctamente, pero en unix puedes añadir un `&` al final de un comando cuando lo lanzas desde el shell, y entonces se ejecutará en segundo plano. Si quieres que siga en ejecución incluso después de cerrar el terminal puedes lanzarlo con `nohup`. En todo caso coincido con @M.Gress en que la mejor opción parece `cron` para el caso de ejecuciones periódicas de un script (en ese caso no necesitas un bucle ni un `sleep()` en tu código, sólo lo que quieras hacer, y es `cron` quien lo lanza cada cierto tiempo que le indiques)

Comment: apoyando los comentarios complementando que si quieres verlo basta con ejecutar el comando `ps -aux | grep python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución es utilizar la herramienta **screen**. Para instalarla en linux:

```
sudo apt install screen
```

Pongamos un ejemplo, si quieres ejecutar tu script, ex: **prueba.py**:

```
#/S session name; 

screen -S python-pruebas

#Ahora entras en screen y ejecutas el script

python prueba.py
```

Para minimizar la pantalla (y que se quede en segundo plano) puedes hacerlo con las siguientes teclas:

> Ctrl + a + d

Para volver a la pantalla donde has ejecutado el script:

```
screen -r
```

Para ver todas las screen:

```
scren -ls
```

Espero que esto pueda ayudar ;)

Comment: También puedes, para agilizar las pruebas, (si no es necesario especificar un nombre de sesión en concreto) hacer un `screen python prueba.py` de esa manera arrancas ya un screen con el script ejecutando.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo estas ejecutando en linux te recomiendo utilizar systemctl y su timer, te dejo un enlace donde puedes checar un ejemplo: https://blog.adrianistan.eu/2017/07/25/timers-systemd-reemplazo-cron/

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar un crontab que ejecute el script de python cada 5 minutos

*/5 * * * * python /home/test/cron/example1.py